How to avoid build errors on "suggestions"?
I have a .NET 8 project I'm trying to build.
I get so many errors.
For example,

Now, in the editor, this "error" is set to "suggestion."

Here's my Code Style settings.

And finally, here's my .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>false</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.3.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates" Version="4.6.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.6.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.21.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="8.0.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="8.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="3.0.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3"/>
        <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.15.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="8.0.2"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="6.7.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache" Version="1.2.0"/>
        <PackageReference Update="NuProj.Common" Version="0.11.30">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Internal.Analyzers" Version="2.9.7">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Update="OSS.RoslynAnalysis" Version="1.4.11"/>
        <PackageReference Update="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Remove="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Where do I change the severity of this error and why changing its severity in the editor does not reflect during build?
I do not have any style/editor config files.
Thanks!

The editor is JetBrains Rider? The C# compiler (csc) will use a .editorConfig if you create one

You have a bunch of different analyzers here. I suggest picking one and aligning your code base with it. I'd stick with the Microsoft ones.
On top of the analyzer packages you're using, Rider has its own analyzers which is what you've been configuring in the IDE. These add even more noise.
The SA1633 in your screenshot and SAXXXX in general are StyleCop analyzers. The way to configure those is not through the IDE, but as described in the StyleCop documentation. However, I suggest to simply stay away from stylecop completely. The stylecop analyzers are extremely out of date and don't support new language features. They support C# 8 at best, which corresponds to dotnet 3. Dotnet 8 supports C# 12.
Well-behaved analyzers should respect the configuration specified in .editorconfig/globalconfig files. The stylecop documentation doesn't mention .editorconfig, but it is supported. Rider's analyzers definitely support these files as well.

Disabling the Roslyn Analyzers used in your project, as suggested by Malt, will make the inspection more effective and reduce unnecessary noise.
The problematic inspection appears to be coming from StyleCop.Analyzer, which is the Roslyn Analyzer version of StyleCop. This is why you can see the configuration in your Rider's context actions, but the StyleCop support is disabled in your IDE settings.
To avoid conflicts, choose one analyzer for your project. Personally, I find Rider's code inspection sufficient without any Roslyn Analyzers.
